# iOS 9 support with IBM worklight 6.1.0.2

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

As your aware apple is launching the iOS 9 what are the prereqs or steps needed to check with existing worklight versions , I am currently using WL 6.1.0.2 and what could be the checks / updates to be carried out to support iOS 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the IBM MobileFirst Platform Developer Center.
A blog post will be published with required actions items.

For now you can read these blog posts:

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/09/mobilefirst-platform-support-for-ios-9/
- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/09/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/
- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/07/preparing-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-server-app-transport-security-ios-9/

Comment: The links are broken, can you please provide updated links.